# Default binding when Source and DataContext are not specifed

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to get to grips with some of the nuances of data binding in WPF. I understand that one may specify a source directly on the binding (using `Source`, `RelativeSource`, etc.) or rely on a `DataContext` within the target's object hierarchy such that the first set value of `DataContext` encountered traversing the target's ancestors provides the source for any bindings.

What I haven't been able to work out is what happens if the source is not set in some way (i.e. the `DataContext` has not been explicitly set anywhere in the target's ancestry and the binding only specifies a `Path`).

1. Where (if anywhere) does the binding engine look for the source property specified in `Path`?
2. Why do I not seem to get any error in the VS "Output" window if the binding fails in this situation (binding errors are normally shown here)?

(.net 4.5, VS 2012 RC, Win 7 32-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that your binding doesn't bind to anything. That's not a binding error, since you don't have to set DataContext explicitly (it is inherited from other elements further up the logical tree), so it is perfectly valid to have a control that waits for its DataContext to be set.

Comment: Of course! I hadn't considered the problem of not wanting or not being able to bind immediately, but that's obviously useful and not binding at all in this situation is therefore very reasonable.